# Porque sale el siguiente error al consultar una tabla usando Hibernate y Java?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

Debo de realizar una consulta a bd a través de un parámetro usando hibernate y este es mi flujo actual

**Controller**

```html
@RequestMapping(value= "/consulta", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String operacionConsulta(@ModelAttribute("consulta") ConsultaVo entrada, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
 request.getSession.setAttribute("consulta", entrada);
 entrada.setFolio("MB123S");
    List<EntidadDatos> listEntidad;
 listEntidad = service.consultaFolio(entrada);
    
 return "views/pantallaConsulta";
}
```

**ServiceImpl**

```html
public List<EntidadDatos> consultaFolio(ConsultaVo entrada){

 String folio = entrada.getFolio();
 
 return repository.consultaFolio(folio);

}
```

**RepositoryImpl**

```html
private static final String FROM_ENTIDAD = " FROM EntidadDatos bit";
private static final String WHERE = " WHERE ";


public List<EntidadDatos> consultaFolio(String folio){

 String stQuery = getQueryConsulta(folio);
 TypedQuery<EntidadDatos>query = em.createQuery(stQuery,EntidadDatos.class);
 query=getTypeQueryCons(query,folio);
 
 return query.getResultList();

}

private String getQueryConsulta(String folio){
StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
stb.append(" SELECT bit");
stb.append(FROM_ENTIDAD);
stb.append(WHERE);
stb.append(queryUtil.obtenerFolio(folio));

return stb.toString();

}

private <E> TypedQuery<E> getTypeQueryCons(TypedQuery<E> typeQuery, String folio){
TypedQuery<E> query = typeQuery;
query = queryUtil.asignaFolio(query, folio);
return query;

}
```

**QueryUtilImpl**

```html
public String obtenerFolio(String folio){
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 if(folio.length() > 0){
  sb.append(" bit.folio =:folio");
 }
 return sb.toString();
}


public <E> TypedQuery<E> asignaFolio(TypedQuery<E> typeQuery, String folio){
 TypedQuery<E> query = typeQuery;
 if(folio.length() > 0){
  query.setParameter("folio", folio);
 }
 return query;
}
```

y al ejecutar me sale el siquiente error

```html
Exception Description:Problem Compiling [SELECT bit FROM EntidadDatos bit WHERE bit.folio =:folio]

The abstract schema type 'EntidadDatos' is unknown
The state field path 'bit.folio' cannot be resolved to a valid type
```

Alguien que me pueda ayudar por que sale el error, nunca he usado hibernate

Comment: En base a lo que te respondí, necesitaríamos ver como es la implementación de tu clase EntidadDatos

Answer (score 0):

En tu query estás tratando de hacer **'bit.folio'** y para esto tienes que tener un atributo llamado **folio** en tu entidad y su respectivo **getter**. Hibernate necesita este get en tu clase para poder traducir **'bit.folio'** a SQL.

Comment: Saludos, si tienes preguntas que hacerle al OP con respecto de su publicación, por favor usa la zona de comentarios justo debajo